# C++ overloading getter twice, one returning pointer and the other const reference, fails

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants, getter

As the title says, I am trying to overload a getter to return both a pointer ([mutator](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-overloading) method) and a const reference ([inspector](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-overloading) method) to a member variable.

Please note that the example in the link above uses a reference and a const reference, I don't want this.

```
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A() : v() {}
    const std::vector<int>& get_v() const {return  v;}
    std::vector<int>*       get_v()       {return  &v;}
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.get_v()->size();  // ok
    a.get_v().size();   // error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘a.A::get_v()’,
                        //        which is of pointer type ‘std::vector<int>*’
                        //        (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
}
```

It seems to work ok until I try to use it throwing the error description given above.
Is there a reason (and a fix) for this misbehaviour?

Comment: Why have one function return a pointer and the other return a reference? Have *both* getters return a reference, one constant and the other non-constant. (I.e. change your pointer-returning function to `std::vector<int>& get_v() { return v; }`)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for comment, but as I explicitly stated in my question this is not what I want.

Comment: @fotis: But why? It could have an impact on the answer. Returning a `const` and non-`const` reference is the 'standard' way of doing this in C++. Your current code is always picking the `non-const` overload, because `a` is non-const; if you want the `const` overload, you would need `const_cast<A const &>(a).get_v().size()`.

Comment: Can you please explain *why* you don't want to follow common practice,  and instead use a function returning a pointer? The compiler is usually very good at picking the correct overload for the situation.

Comment: Code style guides force me to use pointers for mutable data and const reference for everything else. But I think this goes beyond the scope of this _specific question_.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Well, it makes sense that there's some requirements that you should follow, but I would say that the requirement itself doesn't make much sense. :)

Comment: The correct advise would be "avoid getters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems to work ok until I try to use it throwing the error description given above.

```
a.get_v().size();
```

That code is obviously wrong, because `std::vector<int>* get_v()` returns a pointer. The error message is quite clear about trying to access a member of a pointer, that's something you cannot do. To fix it, you need to use the arrow operator to dereference the pointer, like you do on the line above.

> How can you say which one is used?

One overload is non-const and can only be called on non-const objects. The other is const and could be called on both const and non-const objects, but it won't ever be called on non-const objects, because the non-const overload is preferred. It's preferred because it doesn't require conversion of the non-const object parameter to const. The call to const member function would require such conversion. Overloads that don't require a conversion of an argument are preferred over those that do require a conversion. Therefore, the non-const version is always called for non-const object arguments.

> the following also fails

```
std::vector<int>& v = a.get_v();
```

`a` is still non-const and therefore the overload that returns a pointer is chosen. You cannot bind a non-pointer reference to a pointer.

---

If you want to call the function that returns a const reference on a non-const object, then you must give it another name so that it doesn't have an overload that would be preferred over it.

---

> Do you have a reference for this?

I'll quote [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) since this is pretty basic stuff - even though the rules are a bit complex. Look up the standard if you doubt it's correctness.

First, little bit about member function overloads:

> If any candidate function is a member function (static or non-static), but not a constructor, it is treated as if it has an extra parameter (implicit object parameter) which represents the object for which they are called and appears before the first of the actual parameters.

I think it's obvious that both overloads are candidates, since they have the same name. They're also viable because they have the correct number of arguments and they're convertible. Then, which overload is preferred?

> For each pair of viable function F1 and F2, the implicit conversion sequences from the i-th parameter to i-th argument are ranked to determine which one is better
>
> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit conversions for all arguments of F2, and
>
> 1) there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2
>
> ...

Ok, so better conversion sequences are preferred... Which is better? Let's first figure out what the conversion sequences are. The only argument is the implicit object argument. The type of the passed argument is non-const `A`.

The overload that is a non-const has an implicit object argument of type non-const `A` (it's not really relevant here, but it's passed as a pointer in practice). Non-const `A` requires no conversion to non-const `A` because it's an exact match. This will be considered as a identity conversion.

The overload that is const has an implicit object argument of type `const A`. `A` can be implicitly converted to `const A`.

Both conversions are of the same rank. There is lengthy list of rules to go through in that case. None of those apply, until the last part:

> f) Or, if not that, S1 and S2 only differ in qualification conversion, and the cv-qualification of the result of S1 is a subset of the cv-qualification of the result of S2

Identity conversion is a subset of a constness conversion. Therefore it's better. I think that identity might also better because cv-conversion requires two conversions when counting the identity conversion... I can't find a rule about that though.

Comment: Please note that the getter is overloaded (there are two of them).

Comment: @fotis correct, but you're using the non-const overload which returns a pointer.

Comment: How can you say which one is used? Please note that the following also fails `const std::vector<int>& v = a.get_v();`

Comment: _The other is const and could be called on both const and non-const objects, but it won't ever be called on non-const objects, because the non-const overload is preferred [....] Therefore, the non-const version is always called for non-const object arguments._ This pretty much seems to be the answer. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @fotis There's a lot of overload resolution rules, but I put together the relevant ones for you.

Answer (score 3):

`A a` isn't const, so compiler can't apply `const std::vector<int>& get_v() const {return  v;}`

This works:

```
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A() : v() {}
    const std::vector<int>& get_v() const {return  v;}
    std::vector<int>*       get_v()       {return  &v;}
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.get_v()->size();  // ok
    const A b;
    b.get_v().size();   // ok
}
```

*Edited - added explanation*

Why `b.get_v()->size();` fails?

From [there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution):

> Best viable function
>
> For each pair of viable function F1 and F2, the implicit conversion sequences from the i-th parameter to i-th argument are ranked to determine which one is better [...]
>
> 1) there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2

Case 1: `const std::vector<int>& get_v() const {return  v;}`
We don't need to convert anything

Case 2: `std::vector<int>*       get_v()       {return  &v;}`
We need to convert pointer `this` from `const A` to `A` - we can't do it implicitly, only with `const_cast`

So compiler chose case 1.

Comment: Then this part fails: `b.get_v()->size();`

Comment: Yes, it fails. @user2079303 provides explanation: One overload is non-const and can only be called on non-const objects.